# Data location must be "calldata" for parameter in external function, but none was given. --> Undeclared identifier

Tags: compiler-errors, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

In Remix, I'm getting the following error.

```
contracts/TestBench.sol:138:30:
TypeError: Data location must be "calldata" for parameter
in external function, but none was given.
    function updateTokenName(string _name) external onlyOwner { 
                             ^----------^
```

That error references the below line of code (full smart contract is appended at the bottom).

```
function updateTokenName(string _name) external onlyOwner {
```

Then, after replacing the above problematic line with the following line like this:

```
function updateTokenName(string calldata _name) external onlyOwner {
```

I get a series of new errors that look like this. They all reference previous lines of code that passed the compiler without errors before I made the "fix" by adding `calldata`.

```
contracts/TestBench.sol:52:9:
DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _tokens; / ...
        ^-----^
```

The full function that error references is as follows.

```
function approve(address _spender, uint256 _tokens) external { 
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _tokens; // Allow spender to withdraw from msg.sender's account multiple times, up to the specified amount of tokens. 
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix these errors? What is the proper way to declare the identifiers the error message is referencing?

###### Full smart contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0; 
contract FractionalizedAssets {

    address public owner; // contract creator

    mapping (address => uint) public tokenBalanceOf; // map of address and token balance 

    constructor() public { 
        owner = msg.sender; 
    }

    function mint(uint256 _amount, address _to) external onlyOwner {
        require(_amount > 0);  
        tokenBalanceOf[_to] += _amount; // Increase the token balance for user's account by specified amount.     
    }

    function transfer(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokens) external { // Allow users to trade tokens between each other
        require(tokenBalanceOf[_from] >=_tokens && _tokens > 0); // Ensure that sender has enough tokens to send
        tokenBalanceOf[_from] -=_tokens; // Substract tokens from sender's account
        tokenBalanceOf[_to] +=_tokens; // Add tokens to receiver's account
        emit Transfer(_from,_to,_tokens); // Notify listeners about transfer event
    }
    
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require( msg.sender == owner );
        _;
    }

    function burn(uint256 _amount, address _from) external onlyOwner { 
        require(_amount > 0);
        tokenBalanceOf[_from] -= _amount; // Decrease the token balance for user's account by specified amount.     
    }

    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256) { 
       return address(this).balance; // Return the total supply of tokens in circulation. 
    }

    function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256) { 
        return tokenBalanceOf[_owner]; // Return the token balance of specified address. 
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokens) external { 
        require(_tokens > 0 && tokenBalanceOf[_from] >=_tokens); // Ensure that sender has enough tokens to send
        tokenBalanceOf[_from] -=_tokens; // Substract tokens from sender's account
        tokenBalanceOf[_to] +=_tokens; // Add tokens to receiver's account
        emit Transfer(_from,_to,_tokens); // Notify listeners about transfer event
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _tokens) external { 
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _tokens; // Allow spender to withdraw from msg.sender's account multiple times, up to the specified amount of tokens. 
    }

    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256) {
        return allowed[_owner][_spender]; // Return the remaining number of tokens that spender is still allowed to withdraw from owner's account.
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokens) external { 
        require(_tokens > 0 && tokenBalanceOf[_from] >=_tokens && allowed[_from][msg.sender] >=_tokens); // Ensure that sender has enough tokens to send
        tokenBalanceOf[_from] -= _tokens; // Substract tokens from sender's account
        tokenBalanceOf[_to] += _tokens; // Add tokens to receiver's account
        allowed[_from][msg.sender] -= _tokens; // Decrease the amount of remaining tokens spender is still allowed to withdraw from owner's account
        emit Transfer(_from,_to,_tokens); // Notify listeners about transfer event
    }

    function increaseApproval(address _spender, uint256 _addedValue) external { 
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] += _addedValue; // Increase the amount of tokens that spender is still allowed to withdraw from owner's account. 
    }
    
    function decreaseApproval(address _spender, uint256 _subtractedValue) external {
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] -= _subtractedValue; // Decrease the amount of tokens that spender is still allowed to withdraw from owner's account.
    }

    function burnFrom(address _from, uint256 _tokens) external { 
        require(_tokens > 0 && tokenBalanceOf[_from] >=_tokens && allowed[_from][msg.sender] >=_tokens); // Ensure that sender has enough tokens to send
        tokenBalanceOf[_from] -=_tokens; // Substract tokens from sender's account
        allowed[_from][msg.sender]-=_tokens; // Decrease the amount of remaining tokens spender is still allowed to withdraw from owner's account
        emit Burn(_from,_to,_tokens); // Notify listeners about transfer event
    }

    event Burn(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    function burnAll(address _from) external onlyOwner { 
        uint256 balance = tokenBalanceOf[_from]; // Get the user's current token balance. 
        require(balance > 0); // Ensure that user has tokens to burn. 
        tokenBalanceOf[_from] = 0; // Set the user's token balance to zero. 
        emit Burn(_from, address(0), balance); // Notify listeners about transfer event.  
    }

    function pause() external onlyOwner { 
        paused = true; // Set the contract to a paused state. 
        emit Pause(); // Notify listeners about transfer event.  
    }

    function unpause() external onlyOwner {
        paused = false; // Set the contract to an unpaused state.
    }

    event Pause();
    
    function renounceOwnership() external onlyOwner { 
        emit OwnershipRenounced(owner); // Notify listeners about transfer event.  
        owner = address(0); // Set the contract's owner to zero. 
    }

    event OwnershipRenounced(address indexed previousOwner);


    function transferOwnership(address _newOwner) external onlyOwner { 
        require(_newOwner != address(0)); // Ensure that new owner is not zero. 
        emit OwnershipTransferred(owner, _newOwner); // Notify listeners about transfer event.  
        owner = _newOwner; // Set the contract's owner to the new owner. 
    } 

    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);

    function reclaimEther() external onlyOwner { 
        owner.transfer(address(this).balance); // Transfer all ether in the contract to the owner's address. 
        emit ReclaimEther(); // Notify listeners about transfer event.  
    } 
    
    event ReclaimEther();

    function destroy() external onlyOwner { 
        selfdestruct(owner); // Destroy the contract and transfer all ether in the contract to the owner's address. 
        emit Destroy(); // Notify listeners about transfer event.  
    }
 
    event Destroy();
    
    function updateOwner(address _newOwner) external onlyOwner { 
        require(_newOwner != address(0)); // Ensure that new owner is not zero. 
        emit OwnershipTransferred(owner, _newOwner); // Notify listeners about transfer event.  
        owner = _newOwner; // Set the contract's owner to the new owner. 
    }

    function updateTokenName(string calldata _name) external onlyOwner { 
        tokenName = _name; // Update the name of the token. 
        emit TokenNameUpdated(_name); // Notify listeners about transfer event.
    }

    event TokenNameUpdated(string indexed newTokenName);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.5.0/050-breaking-changes.html#explicitness-requirements)

> Explicit data location for all variables of struct, array or mapping
> types is now mandatory. This is also applied to function parameters
> and return variables. For example, change uint[] x = m_x to uint[]
> storage x = m_x, and function f(uint[][] x) to function f(uint[][]
> memory x) where memory is the data location and might be replaced by
> storage or calldata accordingly. Note that external functions require
> parameters with a data location of calldata.

- Then you had to define `allowed` mapping and `paused` storage variables:

  ```
  bool private paused;
  string tokenName;
  // address1 allows address2 uint amount token 
   mapping(address=>mapping(address=>uint)) public allowed;
  ```
- You defined `transferFrom` function with the same signature twice. you either change the signatures or you have to remove one of the functions.
- emitting Burn event inside `burnFrom` is wrong

  ```
  // _to is not defined
  emit Burn(_from,_to,_tokens)
  ```
- `owner` type needs to be changed because of this

> "send" and "transfer" are only available for objects of type "address
> payable", not "address".

```
address payable public owner; // contract creator
// you do not need public
constructor() { 
        owner = payable(msg.sender); 
    }
     

function renounceOwnership() external onlyOwner { 
        emit OwnershipRenounced(owner); // Notify listeners about transfer event.  
        // owner type is set payable above
        owner = payable(address(0)); // Set the contract's owner to zero. 
    }

// owner to payable in below two functions
function transferOwnership(address _newOwner) external onlyOwner { 
        require(_newOwner != address(0)); // Ensure that new owner is not zero. 
        emit OwnershipTransferred(owner, _newOwner); // Notify listeners about transfer event.  
        owner = payable(_newOwner); // Set the contract's owner to the new owner. 
    } 

function updateOwner(address _newOwner) external onlyOwner { 
        require(_newOwner != address(0)); // Ensure that new owner is not zero. 
        emit OwnershipTransferred(owner, _newOwner); // Notify listeners about transfer event.  
        owner = payable(_newOwner); // Set the contract's owner to the new owner. 
    }
```

Now your app is ready to compile in `pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0;`